# This site can’t provide a secure connection (heroku)

Tags: python, google-chrome, ssl, flask, server

Tried all the steps here: https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-fix-err-ssl-protocol-error

[image: Error]

Exact Code:
from https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/flask/a-basic-website/

```
from flask import Flask

# Defining the home page of our site
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
   

@app.route("/")  # this sets the route to this page
def home():
    return "Hello! this is the main page <h1>HELLO</h1>"  # some basic inline html@app.route("/")  # this sets the route to this page
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not in the right order. All pages/routes should be defined before the app is ran (app.run()). I think the video on the website explains it better than the website you linked.

Also this question is unrelated to Heroku so I would recommend removing that from the title.

```
from flask import Flask

# Defining the home page of our site
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")  # this sets the route to this page
def home():
    return "Hello! this is the main page <h1>HELLO</h1>"

#moved this below @app.route
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Tried changing the code as above, still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure what might be causing the error then. Maybe mention the editor that you are using in the question. That might help others with answering your question. Sorry I couldn't help out more.